Confusion about neural network in stochastic control problem
I am a neural network newbie. I would like to attempt to implement the following architecture deep learning a stochastic control problem, taken from this paper. Here $s_t$, $a_t$, $c_t$ and $\xi_t$ are the state, action, cost, and random noise at time $t$ respectively. $C_T$ is the total cost.

I am little confused about the inputs, outputs, and network architecture. I would say that the set of inputs looks like $\{s_0, \xi_0, \xi_1, \ldots, \xi_T\}$, whereas the set of outputs looks like $\{a_t\}_{t=0}^{T-1}$. The loss function for training would then be $C_T$.
Does this make sense? If so, I am confused about the following sentence in the paper:

A key observation for the derivation of the algorithm is that given a sample of the stochastic process $\{\xi_t\}_{t=1}^T$, the total cost $C_T$ can be regarded as the output of a deep neural network.

It seems to me that the authors are thinking differently about the problem - where is my mistake?
In addition, I am also confused about the architecture proposed: what kind of NN allows me to generate intermediate outputs $\{a_t\}_{t=0}^{T-1}$ that I can then work with to produce the intermediate quantities $\{ s_t \}_{t=0}^T$ via a specified rule?
